# How triggers work with transactions? (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I work in MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012. I need to modify a table, which I know will trigger a change in another table. Being cautious, I want to use transactions.

My question is - if I rollback a transaction, during which the triggers have done their job, will the effects of triggers also be rolled back, or only the directly modified table will be restored?

Comment: I think it rolls everything back but you should test.  You do know a single statement is  transaction?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187844(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes (general speaking), it ill rollback your trigger updates but you are correct in being cautions becuase if there are transactions inside your trigger, trigger configuration (after, before) and isolation level can change that. Do an acid test in a test enviroment to be safe.